# ¿Cómo obtener a los argumentos de una función? (CMD, BATCH)

Tags: cmd, batch

No consigo acceder a los argumentos de esta fúncion:

```
@echo off    

set PATH = %~1

:func <var1> <var2> 
echo %~1
echo %~2
EXIT /B

Set var1=Hola
Set var2=Mundo

call: func var1 var2
```

Si ejecuto el programa así:

```
programa.bat "c:/my_path"
```

Lo salida del programa es esta:

```
"c:/my_path"
ECHO está desactivado.
```

Cuando lo que debería salir es esto (o al menos eso me gustaría)

```
Hola
Mundo
```

Necesito acceder tanto a los argumentos de entrada del batch por línea de comandos como a los de la función... y en todos lados veo que se usa (%~1, %~2.... %~n) para acceder a ambas cosas. Pero así no me fuciona a mi.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de mucho tantear al final lo conseguí (la insistencia humana) :-) ...  Aquí dejo la solución por si a alguien mas le es útil.

```
@echo off
goto :main

:setArgs <argumentos>
set "pth=%~1"
echo %pth%
goto:eof


:func <var1> <var2>
echo %~1
echo %~2
goto:eof



:main
call :setArgs "%~1"
call :func 3, 5
call :func "Hola" "Mundo"
call :func func ciona
echo %pth%
pause
```

Si se ejecuta el programa así:

```
programa.bat "c:/my_path"
```

La salida que se obtiene es esta:

```
c:/my_path
3
5
Hola
Mundo
func
ciona
c:/my_path
```

Un problema menos :-)